# Knockout extender without computed

Tags: knockout.js

I'm struggling with knockout extenders. When I use the example from the documentation which returns a computed observable, the extender can only be attached when creating the observable or by replacing the observable, of which I cannot fully oversee the consequences.

Is there any way to create an extender with the same functionality which can be attached apart from the creation of the observable?

```
//would like this to work
this.myNumberTwo = ko.observable(0);
//somewhere else
this.myNumberTwo.extend({ numeric: 0 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xeu6e2s5/7/

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new observable or computed is the only way to intercept a value before it reaches your original observable. If that doesn't matter to you, then you can try subscribing to the original observable inside the extender instead. This will allow the original observable to change, and then you can act on the new value by updating it a second time with the rounded value. If you have any other subscriptions to the observable they will be notified twice for every change.

```
ko.extenders.numeric = function(target, precision) {
    target.subscribe(function(newValue){
        //Your rounding code here
        var roundingMultiplier = Math.pow(10, precision),
            newValueAsNum = isNaN(newValue) ? 0 : +newValue,
            valueToWrite = Math.round(newValueAsNum * roundingMultiplier) / roundingMultiplier;

        if(newValue!==valueToWrite){
            target(valueToWrite);
        }
    });

    return target;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Feels like it's mainly a syntax problem, since you've figured out how it's supposed to work.

If you want to dynamically turn the extension on and off, I'd suggest a slightly altered `numeric` extender with this style:

```
var myNumber = ko.observable(1.234).extend({ obsNumeric: null });
myNumber.setPrecision(0);    // Gives you `1`
myNumber.setPrecision(null); // Gives you the original value
```

```js
ko.extenders.obsNumeric = function(target, initialPrecision) {
  var precision = ko.observable(initialPrecision);
  
  // When reading, apply the precision
  var computed = ko.pureComputed({
    read: function() {
      var prec = precision();
      var val = target();
      
      return prec || prec === 0
        ? numeric(prec,val)
        : val;
    },
    
    write: target
  });

  // Expose the precision setting
  computed.setPrecision = precision;
  
  return computed;
}
   
var myNumber = ko.observable(1.2345678).extend({ obsNumeric: false });
// When passing null, NaN or false, no precision is applied
console.log(myNumber());

// We can change the precision without loosing our original value    
myNumber.setPrecision(0);
console.log(myNumber());

// Which means we can even go up in precision without resulting in .000
myNumber.setPrecision(3);
console.log(myNumber());

function numeric(precision, nr) {
  var roundingMultiplier = Math.pow(10, precision);
  var newValueAsNum = isNaN(nr) ? 0 : +nr;
  
  return Math.round(newValueAsNum * roundingMultiplier) / roundingMultiplier;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```